# Webforms in class library in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, class-library

I am making a class library in asp.net , is there any possibility to add web forms in class library ( content view files with their code-behind ) so i can run , only with a simple method in the CALLER PROJECT ,a whole web app (thanks to this class library) . 
I searched and i found i can't but If not , is there any near solution which can solve this problem ?

**Thanks !**

Comment: can you share what you have done at the moment ?

Comment: I couldn't share images because i need 10 reputations , but i have just made a simple class library which returns a message ,called in my main project (which contains web forms) to display something . what i want is that the main code ( including web forms ) resides in the class library .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question makes no sense; a Web Forms project cannot be treated as a library.

Comment: An ASP.NET project *is* a class library. It's a dll, not an exe. The .exe is IIS itself. So I am not sure what you are asking for. Are you trying to rewrite reuseable components? Perhaps your needs could be met with a [user control or custom control](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/893667/overview-of-user-controls-vs-custom-controls).

Comment: Thanks , my question ,in other words ,is there any possibility  to make a class library as a web app "template" that we can use every time we call it in another project . using web forms or i don't know . . , anything which can solve this .

Answer (score 0):

> is there any possibility to make a class library as a web app "template" that we can use every time we call it in another project

A "class library" project, in Visual Studio terms, is strictly namespaces and classes - no web forms or controls allowed. And you're right, these projects are easily shared among sites by leaving them in a common source control repository or similar.

In an "ASP.NET Web Forms Web Application" project, you can reduce duplication by moving as much "code behind" code as possible to class libraries, which can then be shared among your team(s). You could even theoretically implement a lot of page/control functionality as "base classes" stored in class libraries and then inherited in `aspx.cs` and `master.cs` "code behind" files.

You could also move as much "code front" as possible into Custom User Controls which could be shared across projects by linking source control to a common repository.

But I don't think there's a good way to "share" `.master` and `.aspx` files. You could set up a basic website, keep it in a common place, and let people copy/paste it for new projects. But I don't know of a useful way to share that UI code among multiple web app projects.